# minimize of sum in javascript in two dimension array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve below problem ,my one test case fail why ?

Given a m x n grid filled with non-negative numbers, find a path from top left to bottom right which minimizes the sum of all numbers along its path.

Note: You can only move either down or right at any point in time.

```
Input:
[
  [1,3,1],
  [1,5,1],
  [4,2,1]
]
Output: 7
Explanation: Because the path 1→3→1→1→1 minimizes the sum.


/**
 * @param {number[][]} grid
 * @return {number}
 */
var minPathSum = function(grid) {
      let firstRow = 0,
        firstColumn = 0,
        endColumn = 0,
        endRow = 0;
    if(grid.length === 1){
        return grid[0][0]
    }

    let firstArray = grid[0];
    let endArray = grid[grid.length - 1];
    firstArray.forEach((i) => firstRow += i);
    endArray.forEach((i) => endRow += i);
    for (let i = 1; i < grid.length - 1; i++) {
        firstColumn += grid[i].shift();
        endColumn += grid[i].pop()
    }
    let cornEdge = grid[grid.length - 1].pop();
    let firstElemt = grid[0].shift();
    if (firstRow + endColumn + cornEdge> firstElemt + firstColumn + endRow) {
        return firstElemt+ firstColumn + endRow
    } else {
        return firstRow + endColumn +cornEdge
    }
};
```

**failed test case**

```
Input
[[1,2,5],[3,2,1]]
Output
7
Expected
6
```

from my point of view above expectation is wrong ? it should be `7` using `1->3->2->1` but how it is `six`

Comment: You may find it helpful to read about Dijkstra’s shortest path algorithm. But suffice to say, you're ignoring many other paths through the grid.

Comment: @fubar how to apply dijkstra algo in 2d array

Comment: @fubar please provide your answer

Comment: Question is difficult *(impossible for me)* to understand.

Comment: @RahulChoudary my thought is that each index of the 2D array would be considered a vertex. I'll try and have a look at this later and will post an answer if I come up with one.

Comment: @RahulChoudary I have a brute force solution that works with the two test cases you've provided, but exceeds the runtime execution when doing a 16x16 array. I'll try and post back later.

Comment: @fubar it would be great if you post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a brute force solution to the problem. It will recursively iterate every possible path through the array, and return the minimum found.

Unfortunately, whilst it works with the two test cases presented in the question, it exceeds the runtime execution limits on [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-path-sum/) for the more complex cases; although it does still yield an answer. For example:

```
minPathSum([
    [3,8,6,0,5,9,9,6,3,4,0,5,7,3,9,3],
    [0,9,2,5,5,4,9,1,4,6,9,5,6,7,3,2],
    [8,2,2,3,3,3,1,6,9,1,1,6,6,2,1,9],
    [1,3,6,9,9,5,0,3,4,9,1,0,9,6,2,7],
    [8,6,2,2,1,3,0,0,7,2,7,5,4,8,4,8],
    [4,1,9,5,8,9,9,2,0,2,5,1,8,7,0,9],
    [6,2,1,7,8,1,8,5,5,7,0,2,5,7,2,1],
    [8,1,7,6,2,8,1,2,2,6,4,0,5,4,1,3],
    [9,2,1,7,6,1,4,3,8,6,5,5,3,9,7,3],
    [0,6,0,2,4,3,7,6,1,3,8,6,9,0,0,8],
    [4,3,7,2,4,3,6,4,0,3,9,5,3,6,9,3],
    [2,1,8,8,4,5,6,5,8,7,3,7,7,5,8,3],
    [0,7,6,6,1,2,0,3,5,0,8,0,8,7,4,3],
    [0,4,3,4,9,0,1,9,7,7,8,6,4,6,9,5],
    [6,5,1,9,9,2,2,7,4,2,7,2,2,3,7,2],
    [7,1,9,6,1,2,7,0,9,6,6,4,4,5,1,0],
    [3,4,9,2,8,3,1,2,6,9,7,0,2,4,2,0],
    [5,1,8,8,4,6,8,5,2,4,1,6,2,2,9,7]
]);

// 83 = 3+0+8+2+2+3+3+3+1+0+0+0+2+0+2+5+0+2+0+5+4+1+3+3+8+3+3+3+5+2+0+0+7
```

```js
const minPathSum = function(grid) {
  let maxX = grid[0].length - 1;
  let maxY = grid.length - 1;
  
  return mapPath(grid, 0, 0, maxX, maxY, 0);
};

const mapPath = function(grid, x, y, maxX, maxY, length) {
  const value = grid[y][x];
  
  if (x === maxX && y === maxY) {
    return length + value;
  }
  
  const minX = (x < maxX)
    ? mapPath(grid, x + 1, y, maxX, maxY, length + value)
    : Infinity;
  const minY = (y < maxY) 
    ? mapPath(grid, x, y + 1, maxX, maxY, length + value)
    : Infinity;
  
  return Math.min(minX, minY);
};

console.log(minPathSum([[1,3,1],[1,5,1],[4,2,1]]));
console.log(minPathSum([[1,2,5],[3,2,1]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do like:

```js
function min(array){
  return Math.min(...array);
}
function sum(array){
  return array.reduce((a, c)=>a+=c);
}
function sumsMin(arrayOfArrays){
  const sums = [];
  arrayOfArrays.forEach(a=>{
    sums.push(sum(a));
  });
  return min(sums);
}
console.log(sumsMin([[1,2,5],[3,2,1]]));
```

Comment: @fubar any idea ?

Comment: `Your input
[[1,3,1],[1,5,1],[4,2,1]]
Output
5
Expected
7`

Comment: @Stack I think you didn't understand problem

Comment: Please explain the logic you seek. *"Because the path 1→3→1→1→1 minimizes the sum."* makes no sense to me. Is that the first two lowest numbers in the first Array added to the lowest numbers of the other Arrays.

Comment: see full problem and submit your answer then check where you are doing wrong

Comment: How can I know what I'm doing wrong, when you never explained what doing right is?

Comment: In regards to these numbers, what is a path? How do you come up with `1→3→1→1→1` from `[[1,3,1], [1,5,1], [4,2,1]]`? Absent a proper explanation I believe we  should vote to close.

Comment: @StackSlave there is an explanation in the original question. You need to get from the top left to bottom right position of the grid, making only moves down or right.